# Do I have to recompile ffmpeg in order to enable a new library?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I want to add the [`frei0r`](https://frei0r.dyne.org) filter library to my existing `ffmpeg` installation on Ubuntu, this is my current configuration:

```
--enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --le-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
```

So to add `--enable-frei0r` to this list, do I need to recompile and reinstall `ffmpeg`, or can I do it some other way?

Comment: If `ffmpeg --help` does not show that option in `Configuration` then yes, you have to recompile ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to recompile ffmpeg in order to enable a new library?

Yes.

1. Install *frei0r-plugins-dev*
2. Uninstall/remove your compiled `ffmpeg`
3. Navigate to your ffmpeg source directory
4. Run `make distclean`
5. Add `--enable-frei0r` to your `ffmpeg` configure line
6. Continue compiling/installing as previously

Comment: Thanks. I feared that was what I had to do, but just wanted to be sure there wasn't a quicker way.